# tt_news: different template depending on record pid? Or tx_news fluid "if pid of record" condition?

Tags: typo3, fluid, tt-news, tx-news

I am running tt_news in an older TYPO3 instance.

Now I have the situation I would like to use a different template for each list item depending on *the pid where the rendered news item is found*.

As there is no logic in the classic tt_news templates, and - I think - TS doesn't look at each record, that doesn't seem to be possible at all. Or is it?

Would it be possible with tx_news and a fluid template? Maybe there is a "if pid of record equals n" condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with tx_news. In the fluid template, inside the `f:for`, where the News items are iterated, you can check the pid.

The partial is `partials/List/Item.html` and a simple

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.pid} == 123">
    <f:then></f:then>
    <f:else></f:else>
<f:/if>
```

will do the job.